# Binary Markov-K Random Generator

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, generator

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

currently I'm working on an entropy encoder (MQ-coder) implementation (cython wrapper and internal c source code). To create a test setting, I want to use a binary markov-k random generator, that outputs numpy arrays as input for the encoder. What would be the easiest way to implement such a generator in python, numpy, scipy, or tensorflow? The transition probabilities p(x|x1,...,xk) and the order k should be possible to specify.

Thanks in advance, 
meridius

Comment: Probably need a little more information about the transition probabilities to help you out. Is there some function that gives this? Or a lookup table? or...?

Comment: Do the probabilities add up to one?  (or: to some  known sum)

Comment: The transition probabilities are conditional probabilites depending on the k previous outcomes (x1, ..., xk). Since it should be a binary process, there are 2**k possible conditions, with k order of markov process. For each of these conditions a probability for (e.g.) p(X=0|x1, ..., xk) should be specified, p(X=1|x1, ..., xk)=1-p(X=0|x1, ..., xk) of course. The transition probabilies don't sum up to one, they are actually independent parameters and determine the Markov-K-process completely.

Comment: @StephenCowley: the transition probabilies should be parameters of the function, that generates random binary sequences. The essential idea of the test setting is to create a random source with known entropy rate  (depending on the transition probabilites), and then apply the entropy encoder to the generated sequences and compare the bitrate with the theoretical optimum.

Comment: So (IIUC) , basically you have K levels of `2 state` Markov chains, which can be collapsed into one `2**K`  state Markov machine. Your probabilities can be represented by a `2**k`  sized vector, indexed by current state. The indices (statenumbers) for the two reacheable states can be obtained by adding a 0/1 bit and shifting/masking.

Comment: @StephenCowley: For example a single test would look like this: set the transition probabilities arbitrarily, generate a set of sequences, apply the encoder to the sequences, compute average bitrate. Since the encoder is context adaptive, the bitrate should converge to the entropy rate, if the context size and order of markov process are equal.

Comment: @wildplasser: exactly... actually I was looking for some "ready-made" function, but I think I can also do it by my self... :-)

Comment: There is  a Viterbi implementation publicly available. Maybe you can borrow some ideas from it?

Comment: @wildplasser: do you have a link to the viterbi implementation maybe?

Answer (score 0):

FYI: this generates a table[256] of probabilities, based on the bits of it's (ascii) input.

Usage: `cat*.c| ./a.out`

;-)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct cell     {
        unsigned nhit;
        unsigned ones;
        } cells[256] ={{0,0},};

int main(void)
{
unsigned state, newstate, bit,val;

int ch;

for(state=0;    1; ){
        ch=getc(stdin);
        if(ch==EOF)break;
        for(bit=8; bit-- ;state=newstate & 0xff ){
                val= ch & bit? 1: 0;
                if(val) cells[state].ones += 1;
                cells[state].nhit += 1;
                newstate= (state <<1) | val;
                }
        }

for(state=0; state< 256; state++ ){
        if (    cells[state].nhit < 1)continue;
        fprintf(stdout, "%2x: %u / %u (%lf)\n"
                , state
                , cells[state].ones , cells[state].nhit
                , (0.0+cells[state].ones) / cells[state].nhit
                );
        }

return 0;
}
```

---

It is funny to see that most of the values are 0 or 1 ; or close to it; or near 0.5 .